# Cannot push to Origin Master to GitHub through Git Bash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I just created a small simple app and I want to push it to GitHub.

I followed all the directions per GitHubs Documention. [Link](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)
(I am doing this through windows, C# and visual studio code)

Everything was fine until I tried to "git push origin master", which is the last step. I get the following error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxxxx/FileParser.git/'
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? I have the repo set up on Githubs page as well.

Comment: did you set your local master's copy  point to remote master?
I mean did you add your origin as remote one? what do you get after `git remote -v` ?

Comment: @user404
I did, ran remote -v and got the following:
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/XXXX/FileParser.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/XXXX/FileParser.git (push)

Comment: any new file created on remote which doesn't sync with local one? can you pull update even there is no update out there?

Comment: @user404 nope.  I tried it and the message I got was repo not found.

Comment: It seems your local points correctly though: you can check again:
`git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo_name.git`
`git push origin master`
Did you try this?

Comment: I did, I ran your CLI request and got the following: remote origin already exists

Comment: what about this `git push origin master` ?

Comment: don't you have the branch name as 'master' in your remote repo?

Answer (score 1):

These steps may be helpful:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
git push -u origin master
```